# React Native Navigation : can't navigate between stack when inside a function from another file

Tags: javascript, react-native, nested, navigation

**I have been able to fix my problem now thanks to Stephan answer**

I'm having a bit of problem with how **navigation** works in **React Native**.
Basically what I'm trying to do is this :\

While I'm in the **Home** stack navigate to the **SubFeed** stack from the **Feed** function called in **Home**.

Here is my code

```
import Feed from './Feed'

function Home({ navigation }) {

return (
    <ScrollView>
        <Feed/>
    </ScrollView>
```

*Home.js*

```
function Feed({ navigation }) {

return (
    <View>
        <Button title="nav1" 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SubFeed')}/>
        <Button title="nav2" 
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: 'SubFeed'})}/>
    </View>
```

*Feed.js*

In my App.js I create my stacks like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <StatusBar
    backgroundColor="#ffa31a" />
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Project">
    <Stack.Screen name="Project" component={Home}/>
    <Stack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SubFeed" component={SubFeed} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

*App.js*

I found that in other file where I use navigation I don't need to import anything to make the navigation works as long as I have { navigation } in my function.

The problem is that whenever I try to press either of the buttons I keep getting the same error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')
> \

When I search for an answer I keep seeing things about *screens* but it doesn't seem to be working in my case.

- I think the problem comes from the fact that I try to change the stack outside from home, but I can't understand why.

If you have any suggestion or even better the answer to my problem I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you include the part you imported these two components? The problem is `navigation` object is not passed as a props to `Home.js` and perhaps the reason is that is not a direct child inside your `Navigation` definition.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why I need to pass navigation as a props, should Feed return the navigation to Home as props is that what you mean? @PooyaHaratian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, Feed component doesn't know about navigation property. So, you can pass it as a prop form the parent Home  or you can use `react-navigation-hooks` and use `const { navigate } = useNavigation();` inside Feed component.

Comment: Thank you, your solution with react-navigation-hooks worked I added what you said and just changed my ````navigation.navigate('SubFeed')```` to ````navigate('SubFeed')````